# <p:dialog appendToBody="true" doesn't call Converter class

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 3.4.2 with JSF 2.0

I have the following in a dialog popup in JSF page.

```
<p:dialog header="Create New Request" style="font-weight:bold"
        widgetVar="newDialog" resizable="false" id="newDlg"
        showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" appendToBody="true"
        modal="true" position="center top" width="850" height="450">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputLabel value="Employee" for="employee" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="employee" value="#{mymb.employee}" 
            converter="#{employeeConverter}">
         <f:selectItems value="#{mymb.employeeItems}" var="emp"
        itemLabel="#{emp.employeeName}" itemValue="#{emp.employeeNumber}"/>
       <p:ajax listener="#{mymb.loadDepartments}"  process="@this"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

        </p:panelGrid>
        <p:separator />
            </p:dialog>
```

If I use `appendToBody="true"`, then `selectOneMenu` `Converter` class doesn't gets invoked, but if I make it `appendToBody="false"`, then `Converter` class gets invoked.

What could be the reason for this? `appendToBody="false"` makes my popup dialog unusable, not able to navigate using mouse.

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `appendToBody` and put an `<h:form/>` inside your dialog(along with it's content).

The purpose of `appendToBody="false"` is to ensure your dialog is rendered within the body (and hence within the main `<h:form/>`) of the HTML output.

Without `appendToBody="false"` , the dialog might end up being appended to the end of the markup in `<body/>` and as a result, nothing inside it will get executed.

Adding `<h:form/>` to your dialog ensures that even if it winds up outside the `<body/>` it will still be able to submit to the server

Comment: kolossus Thanks, reason why I have put <h:form> outside dialog is because I am calling popup dialog from a button and update of that button I have given as :formname:idofdialog.

Comment: Another point is I have put <h:form> inside dialog, when I open dialog, popup shows same as when I use appendToBody="false", i.e. cannot use components with mouse, only tab key I am able to navigate.

Comment: kolossus If I use put <h:form> inside dialog and use appendToBody="true", Converter class gets invoked.

Comment: kolossus Yes, I am using appendToBody="true" though. Thanks

Comment: @Polppan, that's actually for the best because without it, the dialog could possibly wind up in the body and cause nested `<h:form/>`s to be generated. Good call