# Primefaces p:orderList java backing list does not update

Tags: jsf, primefaces, facelets

I am currently implementing a orderable list using PrimeFaces'  component, embedded inside a . I was able to get the list to appear properly with my items. However, when I saved the list and submitted it back to the server, the rearranged items did not get reflected in the backing bean for some reason. Since the Primefaces showcase was able to see the changes, what am I doing wrong?

**XHTML Snippet**:

```
<h:form id="confirmDialogForm">
            <p:confirmDialog id="arrangeProjDialog" widgetVar="arrangeDlg" width="600"
                header="Meeting Order" 
                appendToBody="true" message="Drag and drop to rearrange meeting order">     

            <p:orderList id="arrangeProjDialogList" 
                value="#{adminMeetingListBean.orderProjList}"
                converter="#{adminMeetingListBean.rowConverter}"
                var="po"
                controlsLocation="left"
                styleClass="wideList"
                itemLabel="#{po.projectTitle}" 
                itemValue="#{po}"
                >
                <f:facet name="caption">Proposals</f:facet> 
            </p:orderList>

                <p:commandButton value="Save" ajax="true" process="arrangeProjDialogList @this" 
                    actionListener="#{adminMeetingListBean.updateProposalMeetingOrder}" onclick="arrangeDlg.hide();">
                </p:commandButton>
                <p:button value="Cancel" onclick="arrangeDlg.hide(); return false;" />
            </p:confirmDialog>  
        </h:form>
```

**Backing Bean**:

```
public void updateProposalMeetingOrder() {

    if (selectedMeeting != null) {

        orderProjTitles.get(0);

        meetingService.updateMeetingProjSequence(orderProjList, selectedMeeting.getMeetingId());
    }

}
```

The List is a list of POJO "**ProposalOrderRow**" objects. This has the definition:

```
public class ProposalOrderRow implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5012155654584965160L;

    private int dispSeq;
    private int appId;
    private int assignmentId;
    private String refNo;
    private String projectTitle;

    public int getDispSeq() {
        return dispSeq;
    }

    public void setDispSeq(int dispSeq) {
        this.dispSeq = dispSeq;
    }

    public int getAppId() {
        return appId;
    }

    public void setAppId(int appId) {
        this.appId = appId;
    }

    public String getRefNo() {
        return refNo;
    }

    public void setRefNo(String refNo) {
        this.refNo = refNo;
    }

    public String getProjectTitle() {
        return projectTitle;
    }

    public void setProjectTitle(String projectTitle) {
        this.projectTitle = projectTitle;
    }

    public int getAssignmentId() {
        return assignmentId;
    }

    public void setAssignmentId(int assignmentId) {
        this.assignmentId = assignmentId;
    }
}
```

**Converter:**

```
@FacesConverter("proposalOrderRowConverter")
public class ProposalOrderRowConverter implements Converter {

    private List<ProposalOrderRow> orderRows;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String newValue) {

        if (newValue.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        for (ProposalOrderRow item : orderRows) {

            String refNo = item.getRefNo();

            if (refNo.equals(newValue)) {
                return item;
            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {

        if (value == null) {
            return "";
        } 

        ProposalOrderRow row = (ProposalOrderRow) value;

        String output = row.getRefNo();

        return output;
    }

    public List<ProposalOrderRow> getOrderRows() {
        return orderRows;
    }

    public void setOrderRows(List<ProposalOrderRow> orderRows) {
        this.orderRows = orderRows;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your converter for orderList ??

Comment: Thanks. I've posted the converter as asked. Problem is that while the converter's getAsString is called, its getAsObject method is never called.

Comment: You need to add tag converter="" in p:orderList too.

Comment: Edited, but the code only calls getAsString(). getAsObject() never gets called, and my backing list never gets updated.

Comment: @futureelite7 that means that the conversion that is supposed to happen during submission isn't happening. My first guess would be the scope of `adminMeetingListBean` and how you're instantiating `proposalOrderRowConverter`. Why don't you just define the converter as a standalone converter instead of making it a member of the managed bean? It looks like you're not managing the lifecycle of the converter properly, making it unavailable during the conversion phase of the request

Comment: I need to put the converter as a member of my managed bean because I need to map the serialized string back to the original object. Also, I tried making the thing standalone, but still it is not called.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by appendToBody="true" in the confirm dialog. Setting it to false solved the problem.

See link here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033101/pdialog-appendtobody-true-doesnt-call-converter-class)